# Trying to write a PowerShell Active Directory Query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write an Active Directory PowerShell query to list all users in a specific OU.  The OU that I am querying also contains child OUs.  The query below is successful at returning the users in the parent OU but also includes those in the child OUs.  I only want the results for the partent OU.  I am not sure how to restrict the query values to exclude the child OUs.  Any assisted is greatly appreciated.  Below is my code:

```
$Outputfile = "C:\outputfile.csv"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=[ParentOU],DC=[domain],DC=[domain]" -Properties * | 
Select-Object Surname, GivenName, ExtensionAttribute2, mail, lastlogondate, distinguishedName | export-csv -path $OutputFile
```

Comment: Please take a look at the parameter `-SearchScope` of the cmdlet `Get-ADUser`. And BTW: You should avoid using `-Properties *`. Insteaad provide the properties you're really after. That reduces the stress you put on your AD. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`-SearchScope` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-searchscope) with a value of `OneLevel` to search for immediate objects of that OU:

```
$Outputfile = 'C:\outputfile.csv'

$getADUserSplat = @{
    Filter      = '*'
    SearchBase  = 'OU=[ParentOU],DC=[domain],DC=[domain]'
    Properties  = 'Surname', 'GivenName', 'ExtensionAttribute2', 'mail', 'lastlogondate', 'distinguishedName'
    SearchScope = 'OneLevel'
}

Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat |
    Select-Object $getADUserSplat['Properties'] |
    Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```